# tomcat 9.2 not picking up config for disabling tls 1.0

Tags: tomcat9

I am trying to disable TLS 1.0 in apache tomcat 9.0.2 , however the property is never taken

below is the error

---

20-Feb-2019 22:51:40.913 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.SetAllPropertiesRule.begin [SetAllPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Connector/SSLHostConfig/Certificate} Setting property 'sslProtocol' to 'TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2' did not find a matching property.
20-Feb-2019 22:51:40.914 WARNING [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.SetAllPropertiesRule.begin [SetAllPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Connector/SSLHostConfig/Certificate} Setting property 'sslEnabledProtocols' to 'TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2' did not find a matching property.

Server.XML configuration file

---

```
    <Connector port="443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true">
        <SSLHostConfig>
            <Certificate certificateKeystoreFile="/opt/certs/newtomcatcert/hello.gi.com.jks"
             certificateKeystorePassword="########*"
                         type="RSA" sslProtocol="TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2"
           sslEnabledProtocols="TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2" />
        </SSLHostConfig>
    </Connector>
    -->
```

---

nmap result

Starting Nmap 5.51 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2019-03-04 19:54 EST
Nmap scan report for hello.gi.com (10.10.100.71)
Host is up (0.0013s latency).
PORT    STATE SERVICE
443/tcp open  https
| ssl-enum-ciphers:
|   TLSv1.0
|     Ciphers (4)
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
|     Compressors (3)
|       uncompressed
|       uncompressed
|       uncompressed
|   TLSv1.1
|     Ciphers (4)
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
|       TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
|       TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
|     Compressors (3)
|       uncompressed
|       uncompressed
|_      uncompressed
MAC Address: 00:50:56:A4:E0:AE (VMware)

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 1.29 seconds

Comment: Welcome to SO,kindly do formatting in proper manner.So, it helps to getting more attention on Question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end it turned out to be a syntax

```
    <Connector port="443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true">
        <SSLHostConfig protocols="TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2">
            <Certificate certificateKeystoreFile="/opt/certs/newtomcatcert/hello.gi.com.jks"
             certificateKeystorePassword="########*"
                         type="RSA" />
        </SSLHostConfig>
    </Connector>
```

Comment: If you configure the connector like this on Tomcat version 9.0.44, you will get the following message:

   
> WARNING [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SSLHostConfig.setProtocols
> The protocol     [TLSv1.2] was added to the list of protocols on the
> SSLHostConfig named [_default_].     Check if a +/- prefix is missing.

Comment: @svcabre: it is just a warning to encourage the `+`-separated notation. The connector will  still work as required.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to configure this connector on Tomcat 9.0.44 you are missing a + sign before the second element TLSv1.2.

So as an example using the Java NIO connector:

```
    <Connector port="443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true">
        <SSLHostConfig protocols="TLSv1.1,+TLSv1.2">
            <Certificate certificateKeystoreFile="/path/to/keystore.jks"
                         certificateKeystorePassword="***********"
                         type="RSA" />
        </SSLHostConfig>
    </Connector>
```

As another example if you want to use Java NIO2 connector. This allows you to use HTTP2 protocol and if you want to activate TLSv1.1, TLSv1.2 and TLSv1.3 then you can use the following connector:

```
    <Connector port="8443" 
               protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Nio2Protocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true">
        <UpgradeProtocol className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol" />
        <SSLHostConfig protocols="TLSv1.1,+TLSv1.2,+TLSv1.3">
            <Certificate certificateKeystoreFile="/path/to/keystore.jks"
                         certificateKeystorePassword="***********"
                         type="RSA" />
        </SSLHostConfig>
    </Connector>
```

And the last example would be similar to the previous one but removing all protocols that are no longer secure (All active except SSLv2, SSLv3 and TLSv1.0):

```
    <Connector port="8443" 
               protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Nio2Protocol"
               maxThreads="150" SSLEnabled="true">
        <UpgradeProtocol className="org.apache.coyote.http2.Http2Protocol" />
        <SSLHostConfig protocols="all,-SSLv2,-SSLv3,-TLSv1">
            <Certificate certificateKeystoreFile="/path/to/keystore.jks"
                         certificateKeystorePassword="***********"
                         type="RSA" />
        </SSLHostConfig>
    </Connector>
```

Comment: You syntax is incorrect: it should be `TLSv1.1+TLSv1.2+TLSv1.3` without the commas.

Comment: The syntax is not incorrect. Both ways are still valid. Your approach is also working fine for me, but I tested this and it works well for me also splitting the elements with commas.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz At least with or without commas you are not going to get any WARNING on the catalina.out log

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I just glanced [at the code](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/c14c86c78889675ba73819cc5a92f37105214b94/java/org/apache/tomcat/util/net/SSLHostConfig.java#L429) without testing.